# How to store and get strings with concatenated variables from database without loosing variable value in python

Tags: python

I store in database a string with concatenated variables but when I fetch it, it behaves like string, and the variable values are not reflected.

Stored in database field I have:

```
"""\
Please visit the following link to grant or revoke your consent:
"""+os.environ.get("PROTOCOL")+"""://"""+os.environ.get("DOMAIN")+"""/consent?id="""+consentHash+""""""
```

I need to be able to fetch it in python and store it in a variable but have the concatenated variable values reflected:

```
someVariable = database['field']
```

But like this the concatenated variable values are not processed and the whole thing behaves like one string.

When I print(someVariable) I am expecting

```
Please visit the following link to grant or revoke your consent:
https://somedomain/consent?id=123
```

But instead I get the original stored string as in database field:

```
"""\
Please visit the following link to grant or revoke your consent:
"""+os.environ.get("PROTOCOL")+"""://"""+os.environ.get("DOMAIN")+"""/consent?id="""+consentHash+""""""
```

Comment: Although it introduces a raft of security issues, you could use `eval`.

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I needed. Why security issue though, anywhere I can  document about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call `eval` on your string to have it, uh, `eval`uate the string as an expression.

Using `eval` is considered dangerous, because it can be used to do pretty much anything you could write code for, without knowing just what that code will be ahead of time.  This is more of an issue when using it on strings provided from an outside source.

Comment: Ok in this case the database field value will only be set by system administrators not any user so it should work without worries.